# How to achieve Dynamic Menu items list based on User Rights Array?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have an application where all menu items are coming from my below file. I want that users should see only those menus who are in their rights array ?. Below is sample spinet out of whole code.

```
 {
        state: 'master',
        short_label: 'M',
        name: 'MASTER',
        type: 'sub',
        icon: 'ti-direction-alt',
        children: [
          {
            state: 'roles',
            name: 'Roles',
            type: 'sub',
            children: [
              {
                state: 'add-roles',
                name: 'Add Roles',
                // target: true
              },
              {
                state: 'edit-roles',
                name: 'Edit Roles',
                // target: true
              }
            ]
          },
```

Answer (score 2):

If I've understood right you want this to create a menù that the user can see. So, in this example, the user will only see two entry named "Add Roles", and "Edit Roles", right?

Create a Menù class like this :

```
export class MenuEntities {
   public state: string;
   public name: string;
   public target: boolean;
}
```

Create an array of `MenuEntities` parsing the Json. I've assumed that the configuration is in this lines of code :

```
children: [
              {
                state: 'add-roles',
                name: 'Add Roles',
                // target: true
              },
              {
                state: 'edit-roles',
                name: 'Edit Roles',
                // target: true
              }
            ]
```

Create the array and map the json res :

```
public menuEntities: MenuEntities[] = [];
// I let you do the logic to parse the json to this array.
```

Once you have it you are up to go. Simply loop in the `.html` file to this array and you got a menù :

```
<ul *ngFor="let entity of menuEntities">
   <li>States : {{entity.states}}</li>
   <li>Name : {{entity.name}} </li>
</ul>
```

**Note: I can edit this answer if you post more code, but this logic works fine**